# How to rank the closest matches to a record of attributes in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, data-science

I have a BiqQuery table (Table A) that has around 1,000 records containing an ID and 15 datapoints that range between 0 - 100. Imagine its like a top-trumps card but with 15 attributes. Here's an example:

```
Record_ID = 0001
Size = 56
Height = 34
Width = 23
Weight = 78
Color = 42
Volume = 8
Density = 77
Smell = 23
Touch = 67
Hearing = 52
Power = 87
Sensitivity = 3
Strength = 78
Endurance = 45
Reliability = 87
```

And I have a separate table (Table B) that has exactly the same schema with around 5,000 different records

I need to take each Record_ID from Table A and then somehow rank the records in Table B that most closely match across all attributes. If I were just trying to rank records based on a single attribute such as Size then this would be really easy but I don't know where to start when I'm trying to find the closest matches and rankings across all attributes.

Is there any kind of model or approach that might help me achieve this? I have been reading up on clustering and K-means nearest neighbor but these don't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

How about a cross join of both tables. 1000 times 1000 rows will generate a 1 million row table. Aggregating this to the most closed ranked value.

We compare the values in both tables by substracting and taking the absolute value: `abs(A.size-B.size)`. In the following example I choose only two entries, you can add more. Arithmetic weights would be `pow(...,2)` instead of abs. But doing normalisation of each variable to a scale from 0 to 1 beforehand would help missleading results; I did not do this here.

```sql
with recursive 
tblA_tmp as (select id, cast(rand()*100 as int64) as size,cast(rand()*1000 as int64) as height from unnest(generate_array(1,10000) ) id ),
tblB_tmp as (select id, cast(rand()*100 as int64) as size,cast(rand()*1000 as int64) as height from unnest(generate_array(1,10000) ) id),
tblA as (Select * from tblA_tmp union all select * from tblA where false),
tblB as (Select * from tblB_tmp union all select * from tblB where false) 

SELECT * 
from (
SELECT A.id as id_A,
array_agg(B.id order by abs(A.size-B.size)+abs(A.height-B.height) limit 1)[safe_offset(0)] as id_B,
min(abs(A.size-B.size)+abs(A.height-B.height)) as distance
from tblA A
cross join tblB B
group by 1
)
left join tblA on id_A=tblA.id
left join tblB on id_B=tblB.id
```

Please ignore the CTE `with` part. Only by using recursive I can make the example tables A and B permanent and not be generated in each step.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I tried this and expanded out the number of attributes from the two that you included to the full 15 but with that and the initial 1000 times 5000 rows it doesn't look like it will scale. My initial test is with 1000 rows in Table A but this would eventually be up to around 10 - 12 Million rows which would be 12Million times 5000 rows. I was hoping that there would be a BQ model available that would help to rank similar patterns of attributes.

Comment: Please provide what kind of comparision you want: abs, power, correlation (Mikhail Berlyant answers).  You can reduce the size of the generated joined table by using a left join with a strong `where` clause. Like the size values are as close as 10 points together. You can also think of defining a value which generates a sum of all columns and this has be to in range for joining.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach (note use of [CORR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/statistical_aggregate_functions#corr) function)

```
select a_id, b_id from (
  select a.Record_ID a_id, b.Record_ID b_id, (
    select corr(x.value, y.value)
    from (
      select as struct value, col 
      from (select * from unnest([a]))
      unpivot (value for col in (Size, Height, Width, Weight, Color, Volume, Density, Smell, Touch, Hearing, Power, Sensitivity, Strength, Endurance, Reliability))
    ) x 
    join (
      select as struct value, col 
      from (select * from unnest([b]))
      unpivot (value for col in (Size, Height, Width, Weight, Color, Volume, Density, Smell, Touch, Hearing, Power, Sensitivity, Strength, Endurance, Reliability))
    ) y
    using(col) 
  ) a_b_corr
  from tableA a
  cross join tableB b
)
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by a_id order by a_b_corr desc)
```

As improvements direction - you can move all those unpivots out up into
`from tableA a cross join tableB b`

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I tried this option as you have suggested but even with a smaller sample of the two tables the query ran for over an hour without completing.